# No acces to jenkins on raspberry Pi 2 (503 no service available)

Tags: jenkins, raspberry-pi

Good evening.

I hope the question does not exist yet. I searched everything and found nothing suitable for me.

I have a problem with my jenkins that I want to run on my Raspberry Pi 2. I have the setup done as described here:

And it looks like he's running. But I do not get access to it via browser.

If I want to connect with http://192.168.2.XXX:8080, I get the message "Error 503 Service not availabele". But the Jenkins is running when I look at jenkins status. What am I doing wrong? :-(

Hope Someone can help

Comment: Ok, the link with the setup i made is not displayed. Sorry. But i think it is a normal setup.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ps -ef | grep jenkins`?

Comment: jenkins   4275     1  0 13:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
jenkins   4279  4275 88 13:19 ?        00:00:11 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
pi        4373  3920  0 13:19 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto jenkins

Comment: And what do you find in the Jenkins log file `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. There are several warnings like:
deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNUNG: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war

WARNUNG: Failed startup of context w.@1d61c3b{/,file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/,STARTING}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

INFORMATION: Started ServerConnector@40af64{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFORMATION: Started @341355ms
INFORMATION: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled

Comment: Is it possible that you have another service listening on port 8080?

Comment: I did a raspiab setup and the only think i installed so far is jenkins. 
when i use netstat -lptn i get:
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -